# Contract throwing VM exception: Invalid Opcode

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";

    contract DieselPrice is usingOraclize {
        event one(string description);
        event newDieselPrice(string price);


        function DieselPrice() {
            update(); // first check at contract creation
        }

        function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
            require(msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()); // Note: better approach 
            newDieselPrice(result);
            //DieselPriceUSD = parseInt(result, 2); // let's save it as $ cents
            // do something with the USD Diesel price
        }

        function update() payable {
            one("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
            oraclize_query("URL", "xml(https://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/fuelprices).fuelPrices.diesel");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is there a certain function that throws this error?

Answer (score 1):

The probable cause for the error is that you modified the original code in the wrong way.

Originally, it says:

```
if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;
```

So, if msg.sender is different than oraclize_cbAddress() the execution will fail.

You changed it to

```
require(msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()); // Note: better approach
```

Now you are dictating that msg.sender be different that oraclize_cbAddress()

You should change it to

```
require(msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress());
```

Also, have in mind that Oraclize will give you the first execution of each contract for free, but then it charges you, so if you try this a second time, you should make sure the contract has balance to pay for the service.